# Order and Sort_By Returning Different Lists: Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a `Piece` object, which has a counter_cache of `Comment`s, with a `num_comments` attribute defined as a method in the model.

Strangely, `Piece.order(&:num_comments)` does *not* entirely sort my pieces. However `Piece.all.sort_by{|p| p.num_comments}.reverse` *does*.

Am I missing something about the way that the `order` method works?

Comment: Did you mean `Piece.order(:num_comments)`?

Comment: When I do `Piece.order(:num_comments)` I get ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'num_comments' in 'order clause': SELECT `pieces`.* FROM `pieces`  ORDER BY num_comments

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense, as `counter_cache` is probably not in the table. But I don't understand why your current code doesn't raise the following error: `The method .order() must contain arguments.` which is what happens when I try to pass it a block, as you have done.